# Realtime sine tone generation with Core Audio

Tags: c, macos, audio, real-time, core-audio

I want to create a realtime sine generator using apples core audio framework. I want do do it low level so I can learn and understand the fundamentals.

I know that using PortAudio or Jack would probably be easier and I will use them at some point but I would like to get this to work first so I can be confident to understand the fundamentals.

I literally searched for days now on this topic but no one seems to have ever created a real time wave generator using core audio trying to optain low latency while using C and not Swift or Objective-C.

For this I use a project I set up a while ago. It was first designed to be a game. So after the Application starts up, it will enter a run loop. I thought this would perfectly fit as I can use the main loop to copy samples into the audio buffer and process rendering and input handling as well.

So far I get sound. Sometimes it works for a while then starts to glitch, sometimes it glitches right away.

This is my code. I tried to simplify if and only present the important parts.

I got multiple questions. They are located in the bottom section of this post.

Applications main run loop. This is where it all starts after the window is created and buffers and memory is initialized:

```
    while (OSXIsGameRunning())
    {
       OSXProcessPendingMessages(&GameData);            

       [GlobalGLContext makeCurrentContext];

       CGRect WindowFrame = [window frame];
       CGRect ContentViewFrame = [[window contentView] frame];

       CGPoint MouseLocationInScreen = [NSEvent mouseLocation];
       BOOL MouseInWindowFlag = NSPointInRect(MouseLocationInScreen, WindowFrame);
       CGPoint MouseLocationInView = {};

       if (MouseInWindowFlag)
       {
          NSRect RectInWindow = [window convertRectFromScreen:NSMakeRect(MouseLocationInScreen.x,                                                                        MouseLocationInScreen.y,                                                                 1,                                                                         1)];
          NSPoint PointInWindow = RectInWindow.origin;
          MouseLocationInView= [[window contentView] convertPoint:PointInWindow fromView:nil];
       }
       u32 MouseButtonMask = [NSEvent pressedMouseButtons];

       OSXProcessFrameAndRunGameLogic(&GameData, ContentViewFrame,
                                           MouseInWindowFlag, MouseLocationInView,
                                           MouseButtonMask);

#if ENGINE_USE_VSYNC
       [GlobalGLContext flushBuffer];
#else        
       glFlush();
#endif

     }
```

Through using VSYNC I can throttle the loop down to 60 FPS. The timing is not super tight but it is quite steady. I also have some code to throttle it manually using mach timing which is even more imprecise. I left it out for readability.
Not using VSYNC or using mach timing to get 60 iterations a second also makes the audio glitch.

Timing log:

```
CyclesElapsed: 8154360866, TimeElapsed: 0.016624, FPS: 60.155666
CyclesElapsed: 8174382119, TimeElapsed: 0.020021, FPS: 49.946926
CyclesElapsed: 8189041370, TimeElapsed: 0.014659, FPS: 68.216309
CyclesElapsed: 8204363633, TimeElapsed: 0.015322, FPS: 65.264511
CyclesElapsed: 8221230959, TimeElapsed: 0.016867, FPS: 59.286217
CyclesElapsed: 8237971921, TimeElapsed: 0.016741, FPS: 59.733719
CyclesElapsed: 8254861722, TimeElapsed: 0.016890, FPS: 59.207333
CyclesElapsed: 8271667520, TimeElapsed: 0.016806, FPS: 59.503273
CyclesElapsed: 8292434135, TimeElapsed: 0.020767, FPS: 48.154209
```

What is important here is the function `OSXProcessFrameAndRunGameLogic`. It is called 60 times a second and it is passed a struct containing basic information like a buffer for rendering, keyboard state and a sound buffer which looks like this:

```
    typedef struct osx_sound_output
    {
       game_sound_output_buffer SoundBuffer;
       u32 SoundBufferSize;
       s16* CoreAudioBuffer;
       s16* ReadCursor;
       s16* WriteCursor;

       AudioStreamBasicDescription AudioDescriptor;
       AudioUnit AudioUnit;  
    } osx_sound_output;
```

Where `game_sound_output_buffer` is:

```
    typedef struct game_sound_output_buffer
    {
       real32 tSine;
       int SamplesPerSecond;
       int SampleCount;
       int16 *Samples;
    } game_sound_output_buffer;
```

These get set up before the application enters its run loop.
The size for the SoundBuffer itself is `SamplesPerSecond * sizeof(uint16) * 2` where `SamplesPerSecond = 48000`.

So inside `OSXProcessFrameAndRunGameLogic` is the sound generation:

```
void OSXProcessFrameAndRunGameLogic(osx_game_data *GameData, CGRect WindowFrame,
                                    b32 MouseInWindowFlag, CGPoint MouseLocation,
                                    int MouseButtonMask)
{
    GameData->SoundOutput.SoundBuffer.SampleCount = GameData->SoundOutput.SoundBuffer.SamplesPerSecond / GameData->TargetFramesPerSecond;

    // Oszi 1

    OutputTestSineWave(GameData, &GameData->SoundOutput.SoundBuffer, GameData->SynthesizerState.ToneHz);

    int16* CurrentSample = GameData->SoundOutput.SoundBuffer.Samples;
    for (int i = 0; i < GameData->SoundOutput.SoundBuffer.SampleCount; ++i)
    {
        *GameData->SoundOutput.WriteCursor++ = *CurrentSample++;
        *GameData->SoundOutput.WriteCursor++ = *CurrentSample++;

        if ((char*)GameData->SoundOutput.WriteCursor >= ((char*)GameData->SoundOutput.CoreAudioBuffer + GameData->SoundOutput.SoundBufferSize))
        {
            //printf("Write cursor wrapped!\n");
            GameData->SoundOutput.WriteCursor  = GameData->SoundOutput.CoreAudioBuffer;
        }
    }
}
```

Where `OutputTestSineWave` is the part where the buffer is actually filled with data:

```
void OutputTestSineWave(osx_game_data *GameData, game_sound_output_buffer *SoundBuffer, int ToneHz)
{
    int16 ToneVolume = 3000;
    int WavePeriod = SoundBuffer->SamplesPerSecond/ToneHz;

    int16 *SampleOut = SoundBuffer->Samples;
    for(int SampleIndex = 0;
        SampleIndex < SoundBuffer->SampleCount;
        ++SampleIndex)
    {
        real32 SineValue = sinf(SoundBuffer->tSine);
        int16 SampleValue = (int16)(SineValue * ToneVolume);

        *SampleOut++ = SampleValue;
        *SampleOut++ = SampleValue;

        SoundBuffer->tSine += Tau32*1.0f/(real32)WavePeriod;
        if(SoundBuffer->tSine > Tau32)
        {
            SoundBuffer->tSine -= Tau32;
        }
    }
}
```

So when the Buffers are created at start up also Core audio is initialized which I do like this:

```
void OSXInitCoreAudio(osx_sound_output* SoundOutput)
{
    AudioComponentDescription acd;
    acd.componentType         = kAudioUnitType_Output;
    acd.componentSubType      = kAudioUnitSubType_DefaultOutput;
    acd.componentManufacturer = kAudioUnitManufacturer_Apple;

    AudioComponent outputComponent = AudioComponentFindNext(NULL, &acd);

    AudioComponentInstanceNew(outputComponent, &SoundOutput->AudioUnit);
    AudioUnitInitialize(SoundOutput->AudioUnit);

    // uint16
    //AudioStreamBasicDescription asbd;
    SoundOutput->AudioDescriptor.mSampleRate       = SoundOutput->SoundBuffer.SamplesPerSecond;
    SoundOutput->AudioDescriptor.mFormatID         = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
    SoundOutput->AudioDescriptor.mFormatFlags      = kAudioFormatFlagIsSignedInteger | kAudioFormatFlagIsNonInterleaved | kAudioFormatFlagIsPacked;
    SoundOutput->AudioDescriptor.mFramesPerPacket  = 1;
    SoundOutput->AudioDescriptor.mChannelsPerFrame = 2; // Stereo
    SoundOutput->AudioDescriptor.mBitsPerChannel   = sizeof(int16) * 8;
    SoundOutput->AudioDescriptor.mBytesPerFrame    = sizeof(int16); // don't multiply by channel count with non-interleaved!
    SoundOutput->AudioDescriptor.mBytesPerPacket   = SoundOutput->AudioDescriptor.mFramesPerPacket * SoundOutput->AudioDescriptor.mBytesPerFrame;



    AudioUnitSetProperty(SoundOutput->AudioUnit,
                         kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat,
                         kAudioUnitScope_Input,
                         0,
                         &SoundOutput->AudioDescriptor,
                         sizeof(SoundOutput->AudioDescriptor));

    AURenderCallbackStruct cb;
    cb.inputProc = OSXAudioUnitCallback;
    cb.inputProcRefCon = SoundOutput;

    AudioUnitSetProperty(SoundOutput->AudioUnit,
                         kAudioUnitProperty_SetRenderCallback,
                         kAudioUnitScope_Global,
                         0,
                         &cb,
                         sizeof(cb));

    AudioOutputUnitStart(SoundOutput->AudioUnit);
}
```

The initialization code for core audio sets the render callback to `OSXAudioUnitCallback`

```
OSStatus OSXAudioUnitCallback(void * inRefCon,
                              AudioUnitRenderActionFlags * ioActionFlags,
                              const AudioTimeStamp * inTimeStamp,
                              UInt32 inBusNumber,
                              UInt32 inNumberFrames,
                              AudioBufferList * ioData)
{
#pragma unused(ioActionFlags)
#pragma unused(inTimeStamp)
#pragma unused(inBusNumber)

    //double currentPhase = *((double*)inRefCon);

    osx_sound_output* SoundOutput = ((osx_sound_output*)inRefCon);


    if (SoundOutput->ReadCursor == SoundOutput->WriteCursor)
    {
        SoundOutput->SoundBuffer.SampleCount = 0;
        //printf("AudioCallback: No Samples Yet!\n");
    }

    //printf("AudioCallback: SampleCount = %d\n", SoundOutput->SoundBuffer.SampleCount);

    int SampleCount = inNumberFrames;
    if (SoundOutput->SoundBuffer.SampleCount < inNumberFrames)
    {
        SampleCount = SoundOutput->SoundBuffer.SampleCount;
    }

    int16* outputBufferL = (int16 *)ioData->mBuffers[0].mData;
    int16* outputBufferR = (int16 *)ioData->mBuffers[1].mData;

    for (UInt32 i = 0; i < SampleCount; ++i)
    {
        outputBufferL[i] = *SoundOutput->ReadCursor++;
        outputBufferR[i] = *SoundOutput->ReadCursor++;

        if ((char*)SoundOutput->ReadCursor >= (char*)((char*)SoundOutput->CoreAudioBuffer + SoundOutput->SoundBufferSize))
        {
            //printf("Callback: Read cursor wrapped!\n");
            SoundOutput->ReadCursor = SoundOutput->CoreAudioBuffer;
        }
    }

    for (UInt32 i = SampleCount; i < inNumberFrames; ++i)
    {
        outputBufferL[i] = 0.0;
        outputBufferR[i] = 0.0;
    }

    return noErr;
}
```

This is mostly all there is to it. This is quite long but I did not see a way to present all needed information in a more compact way. I wanted to show all because I am by no means a professional programmer. If there is something you feel is missing, pleas tell me.

My feeling tells me that there is something wrong with the timing. I feel the function `OSXProcessFrameAndRunGameLogic` sometimes needs more time so that the core audio callback is already pulling samples out of the buffer before it is fully written by `OutputTestSineWave`.

There is actually more stuff going on in `OSXProcessFrameAndRunGameLogic` which I did not show here. I am "software rendering" very basic stuff into a framebuffer which is then displayed by OpenGL and I also do keypress checks in there because yeah, its the main function of functionality. In the future this is the place where I would like to handle the controls for multiple oscillators, filters and stuff.
Anyway even if I stop the Rendering and Input handling from being called every iteration I still get audio glitches.

I tried pulling all the sound processing in `OSXProcessFrameAndRunGameLogic` into an own function `void* RunSound(void *GameData)` and changed it to:

```
pthread_t soundThread;
pthread_create(&soundThread, NULL, RunSound, GameData);
pthread_join(soundThread, NULL);
```

However I got mixed results and was not even sure if multithreading is done like that. Creating and destroying threads 60 times a second didn't seem the way to go.

I also had the idea to let sound processing happen on a completely different thread before the application actually runs into the main loop. Something like two simultaneously running while loops where the first processes audio and the latter UI and input.

**Questions:**

1. I get glitchy audio. Rendering and input seem to work correctly but audio sometimes glitches, sometimes it doesn't. From the code I provided, can you maybe see me doing something wrong?
2. Am I using the core audio technology in a wrong way in order to achieve real time low latency signal generation?
3. Should I do sound processing in a separate thread like I talked about above? How would threading in this context be done correctly? It would make sense to have a thread only dedicated for sound am I right?
4. Am I right that the basic audio processing should not be done in the render callback of core audio? Is this function only for outputting the provided sound buffer?
   And if sound processing should be done right here, how can I access information like the keyboard state from inside the callback?
5. Are there any resources you could point me to that I maybe missed?

This is the only place I know where I can get help with this project. I would really appreciate your help.

And if something is not clear to you please let me know.

Thank you :)

Comment: You're following Handmade Hero, aren't you? I made a Youtube series going over the platform layer on a Mac. This will link you to my video on sine wave tone generation. https://youtu.be/DcL1ON9qWUA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general when dealing with low-latency audio you want to achieve the most deterministic behaviour possible.

This, for example, translates to:

- Don't hold any locks on the audio thread (priority inversion)
- No memory allocation on the audio thread (takes often too much time)
- No file/network IO on the audio thread (takes often too much time)

**Question 1**:

There are indeed some problems with your code for when you want to achieve continuous, realtime, non-glitching audio.

**1. Two different clock domains.**
You are providing audio data from a (what I call) a different clock domain than the clock domain asking for data. Clock domain 1 in this case is defined by your `TargetFramesPerSecond` value, clock domain 2 defined by Core Audio. However, due too how scheduling works you have no guarantee that you thread is finishing in time and on time. You try to target your rendering to n frames per second, but what happens when you don't make it time wise? As far as I can see you don't compensate for the deviation a render cycle took compared to the ideal timing.
The way threading works is that ultimately the OS scheduler decides when your thread is active. There are never guarantees and this causes you render cycles to be not very precise (in term of precision you need for audio rendering).

**2. There is no synchronisation between the render thread and the Core Audio rendercallback thread.**
The thread where the `OSXAudioUnitCallback` runs is not the same as where your `OSXProcessFrameAndRunGameLogic` and thus `OutputTestSineWave` run. You are providing data from your main thread, and data is being read from the Core Audio render thread. Normally you would use some mutexes to protect you data, but in this case that's not possible because you would run into the problem of priority inversion. 
A way of dealing with race conditions is to use a buffer which uses atomic variables to store the usage and pointers of the buffer and let only 1 producer and 1 consumer use this buffer.
Good examples of such buffers are:
https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPCircularBuffer
https://github.com/andrewrk/libsoundio/blob/master/src/ring_buffer.h

**3. There are a lot of calls in you audio render thread which prevent deterministic behaviour.**
As you wrote you are doing a lot more inside the same audio render thread. Changes are quite high that there will be stuff going on (under the hood) which prevents your thread from being on time. Generally, you should avoid calls which take either too much time or are not deterministic. With all the OpenGL/keypres/framebuffer rendering there is no way to be certain you thread will "arrive on time".
Below are some resources worth looking into.

**Question 2**:

AFAICT generally speaking, you are using the Core Audio technology correctly. The only problem I think you have is on the providing side.

**Question 3**:

Yes. Definitely! Although, there are multiple ways of doing this.
In your case you have a normal-priority thread running to do the rendering and a high-performance, realtime thread on which the audio render callback is being called. Looking at your code I would suggest putting the generation of the sine wave inside the render callback function (or call OutputTestSineWave from the render callback). This way you have the audio generation running inside a reliable high prio thread, there is no other rendering interfering with the timing precision and there is no need for a ringbuffer.

In other cases where you need to do "non-realtime" processing to get audiodata ready (think of reading from a file, reading from a network or even from another physical audio device) you cannot run this logic inside the Core Audio thread. A way to solve this is to start a separate, dedicated thread to do this processing. To pass the data to the realtime audio thread you would then make use of the earlier mentioned ringbuffer.
It basically boiles down to two simple goals: for the realtime thread it is necessary to have the audio data available at all times (all render calls), if this failes you will end up sending invalid (or better zeroed) audio data.
The main goal for the secondary thread is to fill up the ringbuffer as fast as possible and to keep the ringbuffer as full as possible. So, whenever there is room to put new audio data into the ringbuffer the thread should do just that.

The size of the ringbuffer in this case will dicate how much tolerance there will be for delay. The size of the ringbuffer will be a balance between certainty (bigger buffer) and latency (smaller buffer).

BTW. I'm quite certain Core Audio has all the facilities to do all this for you.

**Question 4**:

There are multiple ways of achieving you goal, and rendering the stuff inside the render callback from Core Audio is definitely one of them. The one thing you should keep in mind is that you have to make sure the function returns in time.
For changing parameters to manipulate the audio rendering you'll have to find a way of passing messages which enables the reader (audio renderer function) to get messages without locking and waiting. The way I have done this is to create a second ringbuffer which hold messages from which the audio renderer can consume. This can be as simple as a ringbuffer which hold structs with data (or even pointers to data). As long as you stick to the rules of no locking.

**Question 5**:

I don't know what resources you are aware of but here are some must-reads:
http://atastypixel.com/blog/four-common-mistakes-in-audio-development/
http://www.rossbencina.com/code/real-time-audio-programming-101-time-waits-for-nothing
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1467/_index.html

Comment: Thank you very much! The information and knowledge you provided here is absolutely top notch. It helps me a lot. Really. Things make more sense now. Thank you for that!

I can totally see how placing the audio generation stuff inside the callback and handling controls through a buffer would still be very realtime. 
But how would you handle playback of samples or audio streams from data? Then you have to generate audio outside the core audio thread right? How would you sync them? Or like you call it: "a coupling between processing thread and core audio rendering thread".

Comment: I expanded my original answer to address the follow-up questions here.

Comment: Grazie! 

That solves it all for me now. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

You basic problem is that you are trying to push audio from your game loop instead of letting the audio system pull it; e.g. instead of always having (or quickly being able to create *) enough audio samples ready for the amount requested by the audio callback to be pulled by the audio callback.  The "always" has to account for enough slop to cover timing jitter (being called late or early or too few times) in your game loop.

(* with no locks, semaphores, memory allocation or Objective C messages)